# React component displayed regardless of URL input

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router

I'm following a tutorial using the `react-router-dom` React library.

The problem I have is that my navigation header is displayed regardless of which URL I write in the address bar after `localhost:3000`, (for ex `localhost:3000/dflkjfhdlkfjhdf` will actually display the navigation header instead of saying it's an invalid URL)

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MainNavigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupsPage />} />
        <Route path="/new-meetup" element={<NewMeetupPage />} />
        <Route path="/favorites" element={<FavoritesPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MainNavigation.js:

```
function MainNavigation() {
  return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <div className={classes.logo}> React Meetups </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">All Meetups</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/new-meetup">Add New Meetup</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/favorites">My Favorites</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

with all the necessary import statements.

I think the problem might be that `<MainNavigation />`is in the `App()` function which is wrapped in `<BrowserRouter>` tags in index.js.

However I don't understand the mechanism or how to prevent this from happening (or whether it matters in the first place since it probably won't happen once I deploy the app).

**EDIT**: To be clear I want the `<MainNavigation />` component in App.js because I want that component displayed on every page, but maybe not on `localhost:3000/dfkjldfkjh`

Comment: Is the problem that <AllMeetupsPage /> shows for every route?

Comment: @Shaynel, no it's that <MainNavigation /> shows on every route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it seems is that your app doesn't do anything to "avoid" URL paths it doesn't exclusively have a match for. With a path like `"/dfkjldfkjh"` the `Routes` component will check for a match, and not find any, and correctly not return any matched routed component to render. The `MainNavigation` will still render regardless of any route path matching.

The solution then is to add a redirect route to your app to handle any "unknown" paths and redirect the app back to a known, handled route.

```
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
```

[Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navigate)

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, Navigation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MainNavigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllMeetupsPage />} />
        <Route path="/new-meetup" element={<NewMeetupPage />} />
        <Route path="/favorites" element={<FavoritesPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```